# How to find common parts of a string within a List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a neat way to find the largest common part of a string within a List of strings. I would like a way to go from a list that looked like

```
{"1 Some Street, Some Town, XYZ" ,
"2 Some Street, Some Town, ABC" ,
"3 Some Street, Some Town, XYZ" ,
"4 Some Street, Some Town, ABC" }
```

To return a single string `"Some Street, Some Town, "`.  I don't know if that common part of the string will be at the start, at the end or at the middle of the strings in the input list and I think there should be a neat way to do this but I can't think of it.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring

Comment: @gloomy.penguin That's money!

Comment: that's google.... searched for "c# longest common string" and clicked the first result.

Comment: Can I assume spaces are word separators, and that the strings a composed of words? Or it can be any sequence of chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from gloomy.penguin's comment, using http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = new List<string>
    {"1 Some Street, Some Town, XYZ" ,
    "2 Some Street, Some Town, ABC" ,
    "3 Some Street, Some Town, XYZ" ,
    "4 Some Street, Some Town, ABC" };

    Console.WriteLine(LongestCommonSubstring(values));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string LongestCommonSubstring(IList<string> values)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < values.Count; j++)
        {
            string tmp;
            if (LongestCommonSubstring(values[i], values[j], out tmp) > result.Length)
            {
                result = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring
public static int LongestCommonSubstring(string str1, string str2, out string sequence)
{
    sequence = string.Empty;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
        return 0;

    int[,] num = new int[str1.Length, str2.Length];
    int maxlen = 0;
    int lastSubsBegin = 0;
    StringBuilder sequenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str1[i] != str2[j])
                num[i, j] = 0;
            else
            {
                if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
                    num[i, j] = 1;
                else
                    num[i, j] = 1 + num[i - 1, j - 1];

                if (num[i, j] > maxlen)
                {
                    maxlen = num[i, j];
                    int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i, j] + 1;
                    if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin)
                    {//if the current LCS is the same as the last time this block ran
                        sequenceBuilder.Append(str1[i]);
                    }
                    else //this block resets the string builder if a different LCS is found
                    {
                        lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
                        sequenceBuilder.Length = 0; //clear it
                        sequenceBuilder.Append(str1.Substring(lastSubsBegin, (i + 1) - lastSubsBegin));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sequence = sequenceBuilder.ToString();
    return maxlen;
}
```

Note: this assumes first-come-first-served in the event of a tie.